# specifying dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a jar file present in location

```
/path/to/foo2011020.jar
```

I am importing this jar as

```
import org.foo.FOOException;
import org.foo.FOOObject;
```

How do i specify this in my maven build file??

Is there any good tutorial for learning maven.
Will there be two instances in build file 
I have tried various permutations and combinations but it is just not working. I bet this is something fairly straightforward.

Any pointers..
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want to publish the jar to some private/public nexus and you just want to have it on your disk then use `<system>` scoped dependency

for example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
      <artifactId>your-artifact.id</artifactId>
      <version>your.version</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>/path/to/foo2011020.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```